# Host Multiple Domains on One Server/IP

Tags: apache, codeigniter, phplist

I have phpList already setup and Codeigniter project that I want to add in one server.

The phpList configuration which is located `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phplist.conf` has:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName phplist.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/phplist-3.0.5/public_html

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/phplist_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/phplist_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my possible setting for the CI project, but I don't know how to create one.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName listcsv.com
    ServerAdmin admin@listcsv.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/citest/index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Below the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file has a `IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf` so I think this would include the configuration file on phplist.

I don't know what settings and where configuration file should I go,
should I edit on `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` or just add it together with the phpList configuration at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phplist.conf`?

I tried accessing phplist at `http://phplist.example.com` but the site cannot be reached.

I could access the phpList by going to http://server-ip-address/lists/admin on the browser.

Also, I cannot access the CI project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend creating the directory that the virtual hosts will be stored in, as well as the directory that tells Apache that a virtual host is ready to serve the website

```
sudo mkdir /etc/httpd/sites-available # vhost files 
sudo mkdir /etc/httpd/sites-enabled # symbolic links for vhost enabled
```

Tell Apache where to look for virtual hosts

```
sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Add this line at the end of the file

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Save and exit.

For each website/domain create its own vhost

```
sudo vim /etc/httpd/sites-available/example1.com.conf
sudo vim /etc/httpd/sites-available/example2.com.conf
sudo vim /etc/httpd/sites-available/example3.com.conf
```

Enable the virtualhost

```
sudo ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/example1.com.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/example1.com.conf
sudo ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/example2.com.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/example2.com.conf
sudo ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/example3.com.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/example3.com.conf
```

We done, restart your Apache server for the changes to take affect

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Don't forget to point your domains to the web server's public IP address.

Comment: I will work on this, will update if anything happens.

Comment: I think this is the correct solution to my problem. The issue just might be on my side. I could be missing the settings for ports used.